# Does Zend Framework Lock Table before Insert?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I read this on URL:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

If you lock table before you insert and unlock it after that. The speed will increase 40% faster than not locking.

I don't know if Zend Framework does lock table before insert or not?

Comment: Will be 10 - 20 ( and more ) insert / update on script. Yes!

Comment: hardly bulk, i wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ZF doesn't lock it itself. If you want - you have to do that manually.
2. The exact improvement is **VERY** case-specific. No one could say how much would you win (or lose, who knows) if you lock.

If you don't experience any performance issues with your application - don't do that. If you do experience any performance issues - start with profiling and finding the *exact* reason of your issues.

PS: that phrase in mysql documentation is very speculative.